# Unsetting session in PHP

Tags: php, session, session-cookies, session-state

I have a form which is used to insert records into the database and if all goes right redirect the user to the index page with a message (actually set with a session) about the success or failure of the operation.

Now, am able to set the session in add_book.php and display the message in index.php but the message still persist after reloading the page without going away.

in add_book.php. I have this

```
$_SESSION['insert'] = "Record inserted into the database";
                        session_regenerate_id();
                        session_write_close();
                        echo '...succesfully add new book...';
                        header("Location: index.php");
                        exit();
```

and in the index.php, I have this

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['insert'])){
?>
<p class="update"><?php echo $_SESSION['insert'];?></p>
<?php
}//end of isset $_SESSION['insert']
?>
```

Comment: session_start() maybe?

Comment: Have you tried unsetting the session?

Comment: Well, what exactly are you doing to _remove_ the message from the session?  It doesn't just go away by itself.

Comment: session is started already

Comment: are you using `unset()` to remove the session? or perhaps setting it to `null`?

Comment: @patrick I think isset should do the job after it is redirect but after reloading, it should disappear since nothing is set again

Comment: Once something is set in a session, it stays until removed or the session is destroyed. It doesn't just go away because you loaded a new page.

Comment: @tunde no. didnt do that

Comment: doesn't @Manikiran solution solve your issue?

Comment: @patrick then the unsetting will be inside else statement

Comment: You should really go back and review the basics of sessions and if/else logic. You are severely misunderstanding how all this stuff works.

Comment: you do not need an else statement. Once the insert key exists in the session, echo it then on the next line `unset()` it. Simple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try deleting the session after displaying:

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['insert'])){
?>
<p class="update"><?php echo $_SESSION['insert'];?></p>
<?php
unset($_SESSION['insert']);
}//end of isset $_SESSION['insert']
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

try deleting the content of your session variable

```
 <p class="update"><?php echo $_SESSION['insert']; $_SESSION['insert'] = "";?></p>
```